Unable to execute bash commands from GO function (FN project)
When I try running :
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "docker ps")
outp, err := cmd.Output()
log.Print("outp", outp)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Starting command failed:", err)
}

I am having error :
exit status 127

even though docker is installed and docker ps works from terminal, and works if I run the code from a GO file (not using FN project). I think that having this code as a function using FN project causes the terminal to not find commands like docker and many others.
trying the following code :
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "ps")

gives this error :
exec: \"docker\": executable file not found in $PATH

I tried a lot of other commands as well even ls doesn't work. Anyone had this problem before ? I am thinking it maybe a configuration that I need to do or path problem that needs to be set for the exec command or FN project ... (I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and everything is updated) Any help is greatly appreciated.
[Edit]
My FN project environment after executing the suggested code thanks to Eik is :
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=2d6affdfa0d4
FN_MEMORY=128
FN_TYPE=sync
FN_FN_ID=01HZ5VWQM6NG8G00GZJ000003Q
FN_APP_ID=01HZ5VT0E7NG8G00GZJ000003P
FN_LISTENER=unix:/tmp/iofs/lsnr.sock
FN_FORMAT=http-stream
HOME=/home/fn


The error tells you rather clearly what's wrong -- check the directories in the PATH at your executable's runtime, and make sure one of them contains docker (likewise ls).

Will do that, thank you for the suggestion.

...okay, we've got the variables (thank you!) -- now, where are the executables you're trying to run located at? (And do make sure that's a dump of environment variables for the same process that failed -- if you have your program running as a service, f/e, it'll have a different set of environment variables from an interactive shell; similarly, if you look in /bin or /usr/bin, make sure you're looking in the same filesystem namespace where the error took place -- if the code was running in a container, you need to look at /bin or /usr/bin in that container).

Do you mean Fn Project?
I would assume your function is running inside a docker container, which contains no docker binary.
Why you can't execute ls is not clear to me. Could you add your environment to your question?
package main
 
import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
)
 
func main() {
   for _, value := range os.Environ() {
       fmt.Println(value)
   }
}

Edit:
Your $PATH looks reasonable, what is the output of
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "/")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))
}

?

It's not too surprising that (/usr/)/bin/ls doesn't exist in a minimal environment.

@Peter as you can see, also liked in the answer, it's using alpine:edge. It does noch contain bash, but busybox, so it has ash, sh and ls.

Thank you for the answer, after executing that code I got the environment variables and added them to the question as you suggested.
